# serialize RDD with Avro

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, serialization, avro

I have this scenario. We have to provide a functionality that takes a whatever type of `RDD`, with the generics notation you could say `RDD[T]` and serialize and save to HDFS using `Avro DataFile`.

Beware that the RDD could be of anything, so the functionality should be generic to the given RDD type, for example, `RDD[(String, AnyBusinessObject)]` o `RDD[(String, Date, OtherBusinessObject)]`.

The question is: how can we infer the **Avro schema** and provide **Avro serialization** for a whatever class type in order to save it as Avro Data File?

The functionality is actually already built, but it uses **Java Serialization**, this obviously causes space and time penalty, so we would like to refactor it. We can't use DataFrames.

Answer (score 1):

You can write avro files using the [GenericRecord API](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/gettingstartedjava.html) (see the "Serializing and deserializing without code generation" section). However, you still need to have the Avro schema.

If you have a DataFrame, Spark handles all of this for you because Spark knows how to do the conversion from Spark SQL types to Avro types.

Since you say you **can't** use DataFrames, you'll have to do this schema generation yourself. One option is to use Avro's [ReflectData API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866466/using-apache-avro-reflect).

Then, once you have the schema you'll do a `map` to transform all of the elements in the RDD to `GenericRecord`s and use `GenericDatumWriter` to write it to file.

I'd seriously reconsider these requirements though. IMO, a better design would be to convert from an RDD to a DataFrame so that you can let Spark do the heavy lifting of writing Avro. Or... why even bother with Avro? Just use a file format that allows you to have a generic schema like JSON.